# Reducing a list of maps to a list by in clojure

Tags: clojure

I've started to get some functional programming some weeks ago and I'm trying to perform a mapping from a list of maps to a list considering a specific key in clojure.

My list of maps looks like: `'({:a "a1" :b "b1" :c "c1"} {:a "a2" :b "b2" :c "c2"} {:a "a3" :b "b3" :c "c3"})`

And the output I'm trying to get is: `'("b1" "b2" "b3")`.

I've tried the following:

```
(doseq [m maps]
  (println (list (get m :b))))
```

And my output is a list of lists (what is expected as I'm creating a list for each iteration). So my question is, how can I reduce this to a single list?

**Update**

Just tried the following:

```
(let [x '()]
  (doseq [m map]
    (conj x (get m :b))))
```

However, it is still not working. I`m not getting the point as I was expecting to be appending the elements into a empty list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very common pattern in production Clojure code so it's a good place to learn. In general check out the docs on sequences at https://clojure.org/reference/sequences and when faced with similar task, look to see which pattern best fits and explore functions in that group. In this case it's "Process each item of a seq to create a new seq" and the first item listed is `map`

your example might look like

```
 (map :b my-data)
```

Comment: That's pretty of functional programming, the solutions are so simple... However, for someone with from non-functional programming background tries to make the things overcomplicated (like trying to iterate over the collection). Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but are using the wrong function.  `doseq` is intended only for side effects and always returns `nil`.  The function you are looking for is `for`, which takes a sequence as input and returns another sequence as output.  I generally prefer `for` over the similar `map` as `for` allows you to name the loop variable:

```
(def data-list
  [{:a "a1" :b "b1" :c "c1"}
   {:a "a2" :b "b2" :c "c2"}
   {:a "a3" :b "b3" :c "c3"}])

(let [result (vec (for [item data-list]
                     (:b item)))]
  (println result)   ; print result
  result)            ; return result from `let` expression

result => ["b1" "b2" "b3"]
```

If instead you do this:

```
(println
  (doseq [item data-list]
    (println (:b item))))
```

you can see the difference with `doseq` vs `for`:

```
b1    ; loop item #1
b2    ; loop item #2
b3    ; loop item #3
nil   ; return value of doseq
```

Please see https://www.braveclojure.com/ for online details, and buy a good book (or 5) like Getting Clojure, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification, however, not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but this spinnet (using for) is returning me nil as well.

Comment: That is because `println` always returns `nil` after printing to the screen (which is considered a "side effect"). Notice in my example with `for` it doesn't use `println`.

Comment: Hi, just tried the following: 
`user=>(def data-list [{:a "a1" :b "b1" :c "c1"} {:a "a2" :b "b2" :c "c2"} {:a "a3" :b "b3" :c "c3"}])`
`#'user/data-list`

`user=> (println data-list)`
`[{:c c1, :b b1, :a a1} {:c c2, :b b2, :a a2} {:c c3, :b b3, :a a3}]`
`nil`

`(let [result (vec (for [item data-list]
                     (:b item)))])`
`nil`

Comment: See the updates to the `let` expression.  You must return the result in some fashion for it to be visible outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (doseq [m maps]
>   (println (list (get m :b))))
> ```

In two short lines, you break several general rules of functional programming:

- Pass data into a function as arguments, not as references to global
  variables.
- Don't print the results of computation. Return them as the value of
  the function.
- Avoid mechanisms such as `doseq` that work by side-effects.

Despite this, you were not too far from a solution. `doseq` is essentially a version of `for` that throws away its result. If we replace `doseq` with `for`, and get rid of the `println` and the `list`, we get

```
=> (for [m maps] (get m :b))
("b1" "b2" "b3")
```

But [Arthur Ulfeldt's simple use of `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54848643/1562315) is better.